# Unit Testing MVC 3 and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, tdd

I am learning Microsofts built in Unit Testing capability in VS2010 and came across a problem.

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();


        //Act
        ViewResult results = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        //Assert
        ViewDataDictionary viewData = results.ViewData;

        Assert.AreEqual(null, viewData["Message"]);

    }
}
```

I know this will return failed, that isn't an issue. What is an issue however is that I am hitting my EntityFramework model "myModel.edmx" and getting the error `"System.ArgumentException: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid."`

This is in the file MyModel.Designer.cs. The line in question is:

`public Tool_Entities() : base("name=Tool_Entities", "Tool_Entities")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }`
I know this line is ok as when I run the non-test project, I can connect to this model fine.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://bit.ly/bF7jL3. It explains how to build an (LINQ enabled) abstraction around your O/RM.

Comment: Are your tests in a separate project? (in that case the tests run off their own app.config)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should abstract out EF from your controllers in a service-oriented or repository way. That way you can remove the dependency (and inject a mock) for your unit tests and just test your controllers.

First create an interface. This is just a blueprint, you can make it what ever way you want.

```
public interface IToolRepository
{
   void Add(Tool something);
   IQueryable<Tool> Query { get; }
   void Delete(Tool something);
}
```

Then implement this with EF.

Comment: How would I go about that? I am fairly new to the EntityFramework.
I'd guess that I would have to create an interface somehow for the EF model in question?